# How enable pagination on a taxonomy term page?

Tags: php, drupal, pagination

I've created a taxonomy (product-categories), which contains several terms (e.g. electronics).

I've configured the taxonomy to display an image and a description at the top of the taxonomy/term page (set in admin/structure/taxonomy/product-categories/display)

When I browse to /product-categories/electronics, I see the title, description and image at the top, and then teasers for each of my products. All exactly as I want, except it only shows 10 products, with no pagination links.

I would like to know how I can enable pagination on it?
I then tried enabling the Taxonomy Term view, which overrides the default core rendering of that page.

Comment: What is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you adjust the pager settings in the view?